# Yup, how to validate one variable against a function of several other ones?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I'm trying to implement a yup validation schema and lets say I have five numeric values (A, B, C, D, E)

I want D and E be less than a math function based on A,B,C and some constant value. Something like this:

```
const upperBound = Math.min(A,B,C)-10;
if((D > upperBound) || (E > upperBound))
    return FAIL;
else
    return PASS;
```

I have reviewed many threads on SO but none of them address multiple variable dependency.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the test function to achieve that:

```
Yup.object().test({
          name: 'D and E less than ABC', // Your custom error id
          test: function () {
             const {A,B,C,D,E} = this.parent; // Access the object data, here this.parent contains your data
             const upperBound = Math.min(A,B,C)-10;
             if((D > upperBound) || (E > upperBound))
                 return this.createError({
                  message: `D and E must be below min`, // Error message for the user
                  path: `D`, // The object path where you want show the error
                });
             return true; // True for no error
        }),
```

Comment: Thanks, can I daisy-chain tests if I want to add a lets say lower bound?

Comment: Yes that should work as expected, I only know that array min does not work with that, But since you are not using arrays, it should work as expected.

Comment: eslint throws this error `Stateless functional components should not use 'this'` on line `const { A,B,C,D } = this.parent;` . Any recommendations to fix or should I just ignore?

Comment: You need to use function () {}. Not arrow function with ()=>{} due to how this is handle differently between these two calls. Can you share you exact code?